# InvalidIndexError error mapping dask series

Tags: python, pandas, dask, pyarrow, fastparquet

This mapping works when calling `head` on the first 100 rows:

`ddf['val'] = ddf['myid'].map( val['val'] , meta=pd.Series(float) )`

But when I try to save to parquet:

```
ddf.to_parquet('myfile.parquet', 
               compression='snappy', 
               write_index=False,
               compute_kwargs={'scheduler':'threads'}
              )
```

I am getting an error: `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`.

But checking my index (after converting to pandas series), it is unique: `val.index.duplicated().any()` is `False`.  Also, the index is the same set as the dataframe column it is being mapped to: `myid`.  There are no nulls, nans, or Nones in the index.  The index is int64.

Update: curiously, if I load each parquet file for the original ddf one at a time, this does not error.  If I load more than one at a time, it errors out.

Comment: dask 2.20.0, pandas 1.0.5, python 3.6, centos 7

Comment: fastparquet 0.4.0, pyarrow 0.17.1, python-snappy 0.5.4, snappy.x86_64 1.1.0-3.el7

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug in the `fastparquet` engine.  I saved the underlying dataframes with `pyarrow` and used `to_parquet` with `engine='pyarrow'` and things are working now:

```
ddf.to_parquet('myfile.parquet', 
               engine='pyarrow',
               compression='snappy', 
               write_index=False,
               compute_kwargs={'scheduler':'threads'}
              )
```

Comment: If you can figure out the bug, feel free to post to dask or fastparquet, depending on where the bug lies.

Comment: @mdurant Not sure where the bug ultimately lies, but created a toy example that was having issues with pyarrow as well. So, I created the issue under dask for the bug: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/6394.